# how to fix apache2 installation in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache, ubuntu, server, failed-installation, reinstall

I uninstalled apache2 using ubuntu 18.04 , in order to reinstall it. I used sudo apt-get purge apache2.
then i searched for the remaining apache files using Whereis apache2 and manually deleted the paths that had apache folders using sudo rm -rf and then the file's path.

- sudo rm -rf /etc/apache2
- sudo rm -rf /usr/sbin/apache2
- sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/apache2

I reinstalled apache , but the folders are no longer installed in etc and the other paths where i removed them from.
how can I reinstall apache properly.

Answer (score 0):

This guide should walk you through it:  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/httpd.html

It should have placed new files in /etc/apache2.  Did you get errors during the install?